# SQL LEFT JOIN two tables without using GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

organization:

```
---------------------------
|  ID   |  Name | Owner   |     
---------------------------
```

project_clients:

```
----------------------------------
|  ID   |  identification | Type  |     
-----------------------------------
```

project_organizations:

```
---------------------------------
|  ID   |  project_id | orgid   |     
---------------------------------
```

Id like to pull all organizations under project 680 or all clients with type 'organization' under project 680. I can achieve this using the code below but is there other way i can get same result without using GROUP BY?

```
SELECT a.* FROM organization a 
LEFT join project_organizations b on a.id = b.orgid 
LEFT JOIN project_clients c on  c.identification = a.id 
where b.projectid = 680 OR (c.project_id = 680 AND c.type='organization') 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: `project_clients.project_id` ... ? I don't see that table in the description.

Comment: Why don't you want to use group by if that does give you the results you want?

Comment: @GolezTrol Removing the "GROUP BY" will show all rows in table organization. I am thinking there must be a better solution.

Comment: @ypercube Sorry the correct table is `project_clients`

Comment: Please edit your question - as ypercube stated, the various table names don't match up to the last SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM organization a 
LEFT join project_organizations b on a.id = b.orgid 
LEFT JOIN project_clients c on  c.identification = a.id where b.projectid = 680 OR (c.project_id = 680 AND c.type='organization')
```

I think you can also achieve your result in a completely different way with a query like this

```
select * 
from organization a 
where id in (select ordid from project_organizations b where projectid=680) 
or id in (select c.id from project_clients C where c.project_id=680 and c.type='organization')
```

Comment: This is picky, but the original query got the rest of the data from table a. Maybe SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name, a.owner .... ??

Comment: i think this is better.